# Is there a way to remove the title bar in OS X emacs?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, emacs

I'm using the stripped down [emacs on OS X Snow Leopard](http://emacsformacosx.com/). I'm trying to customize it as much as possible.

One last piece of screen real estate I'd like to get is the title bar (where the maxmize/minimize buttons sit) — it's mostly superfluous, I don't need to be reminded of the filename, and I'm trying to get as much of an "immersive", full-screen experience as possible. Any ideas on how to do this?

By the way, I want to put off installing Lion for now (some software I need doesn't support it yet).

Answer (score 1):

This [wiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FullScreen#toc9) should help you.

> *Patching the binary*
>
> To add the fullscreen functionality into Emacs, you can compile your
>   own binary.
>
> The procedure described on this page uses typester's patch from Dec
>   2009. Use M-x ns-toggle-fullscreen.

Judging from the fact that you use emacs, I assume you're already a bit familiar with the insanely <strike>strange</strike> *innovative* language that is Lisp. It seems with the latest versions of emacs, the functionality isn't as good, but it's probably good enough to keep you running until you can use Lion.

Comment: That solution still requires installing a later version of OS X. Unfortunately such versions are not available for PPC Macs and consume too much memory which still prevents many users (such as myself) from upgrading (older notebooks max out at 4GB but even if you have 8GB OS X versions 10.7 and 10.8 perform much worse than 10.6 with just 4GB).

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable driving emacs from the terminal, run it using [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home), which you can set to go full screen from the View menu (⌘↩) (ie. Cmd-enter))

Comment: This has the disadvantage of disabling many key bindings available in the GUI but not in the terminal.